# Django rest framework and React: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: reactjs, django, web, django-rest-framework, fetch-api

I am using Django rest framework for back-end and react for front-end of a website. Back-end is working fine in my Postman app and browser. However, when I fetch data using react it prints following error in my console

> TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

and the following is shown sometimes in XHR tab of Networks. Ignore api/movies/ in File column since I changed the url at the time of editing, for debugging purposes

[image]

Here is my code

```
export default function Contact() {
  const [contactData, setContactData]=useState({
    'name': '',
    'email': '',
    'phone': '',
    'describe': '',
    'status': '',
  });
  
  const change=(event)=>{
    setContactData({
      ...contactData,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }
  const submitForm=()=>{
    const contactFormData=new FormData();
    contactFormData.append('name', contactData.name)
    contactFormData.append('email', contactData.email)
    contactFormData.append('phone', contactData.phone)
    contactFormData.append('describe', contactData.describe)
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/ask/', {
      mode: 'cors',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
   body: JSON.stringify({
     // your expected POST request payload goes here
        name: contactData.name,
        email: contactData.email,
        phone:contactData.phone,
        describe: contactData.describe
      })
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
      // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
      setContactData({
        'name': '',
        'email': '',
        'phone': '',
        'describe': '',
        'status': 'success',
      })
    }
  )
  .catch(error => {
  // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
   console.log(error)
  })
```

here is the part of settings.py file where I added cors headers

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    "corsheaders",
    'api',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'i_CAMP_API.urls'
```

Comment: Are you really sure that nothing shows up in network tab?

Comment: Please recheck question as I have added the picture now. I have changed the url from api a bit to debug. This same thing was happening with the earlier url.

Comment: Have you tried to set cors header on the backend side?

Comment: check in the last code block. I have added the Cors headers